# Destroy CakePHP session when close browser

Tags: session, cakephp, browser

I need to keep Security.level set on medium for Ajax reason.
But I want that If the user close browser his session will destroy.
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't say whether you are using php cake or database sessions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're persisting session data (ie: storing session data in a cookie with an expiration date in the future), then the session should be destroyed when the user closes the browser.

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the CakePHP framework so I cannot comment on its API. However, if you want to explicitly end a session you can do so in PHP with `session_destroy()`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookieTimeout' => 0,   //Lives until the browser is closed.
    'checkAgent'  => false  //To fix a little the Chrome Frame problem
));
```

Comment: its ok but better if you tell him how to destroy it, not make it temporary in the beginning.

Comment: Why is this just "okay"? I think this is the solution, since it will just destroy the auth cookie, and thus destroy your session. Destroying it manually requires an additional ajax call which is dependent on JS, which not every user has turned on. So that's not reliable.

Comment: Configure::write('Session', array(
            'defaults' => 'php',
            'timeout' => 1440, // The session will timeout after 30 minutes of inactivity
            'cookieTimeout' => 1440, // The session cookie will live for at most 24 hours, this does not effect session timeouts
            'checkAgent' => false,
        //    'autoRegenerate' => false, // causes the session expiration time to reset on each page load
        )); //also comment this line it work perfectly  'autoRegenerate'

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the session cookie with JS when the page is closed (remember: page close is also triggered when the user just navigates away - maybe just to the next page of yours).

Answer (score 0):

i guess you could fire on ajax command on page unload to call session_destroy()

Comment: what if the browser crashes? i would do it the other way around: ajax post to a url every few few seconds. if this doesnt happen anymore, the user is not "on the website" anymore.

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1317/destroy for CakePHP - but yes, CakePHP does set a proper session cookie which is deleted by the browser when it closes.

What you really are probably concerned about is session hijacking - and so you really want some kind of a logout on site closure. You can't do this - the best alternative method that I know of is:

- A short session timeout with an "Are you there?" AJAX refresh - the timeout can be controlled independently of the security level now using `Configure::write('Session.timeout', $seconds);`, where for medium security level the timeout seconds are multiplied by 100. Banks use this method.